# mouse pointer keeps blinking during drag event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

So i have som items in tree . Im implementing drag and drop with native javascript as im using GWT and its libraries arent usable for me.
Tree should support copying items (drag item and drop it in another one) and reordering items (drag item and drop between items). Im trying to determine this action according to mouse position but the problem is that during drag event pointer keeps blinking e.g switching between "hand" icon and "plus" icon. This is what im doing in first prototype is only CSS changing:

```
 $doc.TreeOnReorderOver = function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = rect.top;
        var bottom = rect.bottom;
        var height = bottom - top;
        ev.target.style.cursor='none';
        if(ev.clientY >= top && ev.clientY < top + height/4) { //reorder top

              ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

              ev.target.style.borderStyle = 'solid none none none'; 
              ev.target.style.borderWidth = '3px';
              ev.target.style.borderColor = '#D1E4EB';
        }
        if(ev.clientY >= top + height/4 && ev.clientY < bottom  - height/4) { //drop in
              ev.target.style.border = 'none';
              ev.target.style.backgroundColor = '#D1E4EB';
        }
        if(ev.clientY >= bottom - height/4 && ev.clientY < bottom) { //reorder bottom
              ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

              ev.target.style.borderStyle = 'none none solid none'; 
              ev.target.style.borderWidth = '3px';
              ev.target.style.borderColor = '#D1E4EB';
        }

    };
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What does java have to do with this?

Comment: It was just a clarification that im using native javascript. So no frameworks and libraries related advices are good for me

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same thing. I removed the Java tag for you. Having the [javascript] tag shows you are using native javascript.

Comment: Iknow that they are not the same come on :) . But i agree that that tag was maybe misleading

Comment: is the cursor blinking when you are holding it and not dragging it?

Comment: It stars blinking when i drag item over droppable elements. It is probably because of recalculating mouse position constantly

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually quite current. You've set your cursor to not have a pointer on the object you are moving:

```
ev.target.style.cursor='none';
```

So as long as your mouse is hovering over the target (I'm guessing it's the object you are dragging) it won't have a pointer.

When you are dragging the object your cursor moves first (hovering over other elements) and then your object gets moved to your cursor's position. This is causing your cursor to switch back to a pointer.

Try to instead set the `document.body.style.cursor='none';` for the duration of the drag instead.